# Google DoubleClick Inventory Percentage

Tags: ads, double-click

OK, so I've been told to learn how to use Google DoubleClick at work with no previous experience. Our ad campaigns had been set up ages ago and what I can tell from some reading, incorrectly.

All our ads have been set to deliver 100% inventory availability. From my understanding each ad should have a proportionate allocation leading to an even (or deliberately biased) amount of impressions.

For Example 4 ads occupying the same slot on the home page are set to have 25% each, that way they get the same amount of display time and equal impressions. Is this correct?

We currently have 7 ads set to use this space on the home page (one is India only) and several others using the same space but displaying on different pages. would the India only ad for example, assuming my thoughts on percentages are correct, still require a share of the percentage because it uses the same inventory space or does this get reset because of the geo-targetting?